# JS error when using AddThis field displayed in a view

Tags: views, javascript

I keep getting this error:

ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined }(jQuery));

when using an addthis field displayed in a view.

Anyone has a clue what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AddThis includes it's javascript in the footer. It could be possible that, in your case, you have to add addThis in the header.

You can do this by changing this line of code in the addthis.php:

AddThis.php line 274 comment:

```
'scope' => 'footer’,
```

Hopes this help you out!